# Problem in Communicating with Digitally SIgned c# com dll from c++ in WIN 7 ultimate

Tags: c#, c++, windows-7

I  have a c# com dll which I register to registry Using regasm . I communicate with this c# dll from a c++ exe . I  use create instance to initialize the dll . when both these components are not signed digital it is working perfectly . when they are digitally signed cocreate instance fails. get last error says  "Token not found" . this happens in WIN 7 ultimate and PRo where as in xp and vista it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you **re-register** your DLLs using *regasm* once you sign them?

Use *regedit* to check the registration info at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{your-guid-here}\InProceServer32`, eg:

`Assembly   REG_SZ   YourComObjectName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdfc550b465bd3`

If your `PublicKeyToken=null` then this is the cause. To get the token from your DLL use sn.exe tool, eg: `sn.exe -T path\to\your.dll`